# Cassandra best practice to overwrite/update a row?

Tags: cassandra

We are planning on using Cassandra 3.1 as our datastore.  The data model will use a user_uuid as the partition key/primary key, with no clustering key.  The query pattern is to access a particular user's user_uuid and update that row with various data.  The intent isn't to simply add more columns, but to completely overwrite values/columns, ex. timestamp, version, and other various aspects of a user.  The expectation is that there will be about a million different users written to per day, and it could be written thousands of times per day per user.

Is this an efficient way of using Cassandra as a datastore?  From doing research, I read that updating a row in Cassandra doesn't create tombstones, instead it will create "shadows" that get removed when the SSTable gets compacted.

So if it doesn't create tombstones, then is this a safe and efficient way to store data for a particular user?

Comment: "about a million different users written to per day, and it could be written thousands of times per day per user"  If one of our app teams came to me asking for a new cluster and said *that*, my answer would be that **no**, that's not a good idea to do with Cassandra.

Comment: thank you for your response.  what in particular would make you say it's not a good idea?

Comment: My concern would be that updating values that often (10k/day ea) would create so much obsoleted data underneath, that your partitions would become too big and ungainly.  Sure compaction will reclaim that, but updating a column value in-place 10k times per day is just too much.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra model is kind of append-only - every update or delete of key+column pair is saved as new version of it, and not updated in place - tombstones is just a version that says that the row is deleted. So it will be save to use it even with tombstones :). On the time of read, Cassandra will return only most recent value for such key/value pair.

The data is saved in sstables, and when 2 of these compacted, only most recent data for each key-value pair in these tables will be saved after the process.

Cassandra is indeed meeting requirements for your load, and for update heavy workloads i'll suggest using leveled compaction strategy - you can read about it here:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/when-to-use-leveled-compaction

And about write path:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html